# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.android.hereiam.MapsActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Please find the code in my main activity.

```
package com.example.android.hereiam;

import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

// Since it’s the easiest way of adding a map to your project, I’m going to stick with using




// a MapFragment//

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,



        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
    private GoogleMap mMap;




    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;




    Marker mLocationMarker;
    Location mLastLocation;




    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)




    @Override




    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)




    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {



// In Android 6.0 and higher you need to request permissions at runtime, and the user has
        // the ability to grant or deny each permission. Users can also revoke a previously-granted
        // permission at any time, so your app must always check that it has access to each
        // permission, before trying to perform actions that require that permission. Here, we’re using
        // ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission to check whether this app currently has the
        // ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)




                // If your app does have access to COARSE_LOCATION, then this method will return
                // PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED//




                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // If your app doesn’t have this permission, then you’ll need to request it by calling
// the ActivityCompat.requestPermissions method//
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                        },
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            else {
                // Request the permission by launching Android’s standard permissions dialog.
                // If you want to provide any additional information, such as why your app requires this
                // particular permission, then you’ll need to add this information before calling
                // requestPermission //
                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                        },
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Specify what kind of map you want to display. In this example I’m sticking with the
        // classic, “Normal” map

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) ;
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                // Although the user’s location will update automatically on a regular basis, you can also
                // give your users a way of triggering a location update manually. Here, we’re adding a
                // ‘My Location’ button to the upper-right corner of our app; when the user taps this button,
                // the camera will update and center on the user’s current location//

                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        // Use the GoogleApiClient.Builder class to create an instance of the
        // Google Play Services API client//
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)



                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // Connect to Google Play Services, by calling the connect() method//
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    // If the connect request is completed successfully, the onConnected(Bundle) method
    // will be invoked and any queued items will be executed//
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {




        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(2000);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Retrieve the user’s last known location//
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }

    // Displaying multiple ‘current location’ markers is only going to confuse your users!
    // To make sure there’s only ever one marker onscreen at a time, I’m using
    // mLocationMarker.remove to clear all markers whenever the user’s location changes.
    public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
            String message = data.getString("message");
        }

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mLastLocation = location;
            if (mLocationMarker != null) {
                mLocationMarker.remove();
            }

            // To help preserve the device’s battery life, you’ll typically want to use
            // removeLocationUpdates to suspend location updates when your app is no longer
            // visible onscreen//
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (LocationListener) this);
            }
        }

        // Once the user has granted or denied your permission request, the Activity’s
        // onRequestPermissionsResult method will be called, and the system will pass
        // the results of the ‘grant permission’ dialog, as an int//


        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                               String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOC`enter code here`ATION: {

                    // If the request is cancelled, the result array will be empty (0)//
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        // If the user has granted your permission request, then your app can now perform all its
                        // location-related tasks, including displaying the user’s location on the map//
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                                buildGoogleApiClient();
                            }
                            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // If the user has denied your permission request, then at this point you may want to
                        // disable any functionality that depends on this permission//
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Main activity code handles the google api to give me the right location places. 
But I am getting the errors :

> Process: com.example.android.hereiam, PID: 15899
>                                                                                java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.android.hereiam.MapsActivity
>   cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
>                                                                                    at
>   com.example.android.hereiam.MapsActivity.onConnected(MapsActivity.java:151)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzp(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrd.zzn(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrb.zzass(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrb.onConnected(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrf.onConnected(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqr.onConnected(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$1.onConnected(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze$zzj.zzavj(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze$zza.zzv(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze$zze.zzavl(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358) 11-21
>   14:45:42.935 15899-15944/com.example.android.hereiam I/System.out:
>   (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false 11-21 14:45:42.935
>   15899-15944/com.example.android.hereiam I/System.out:
>   (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false 11-21 14:45:44.702
>   15899-15971/com.example.android.hereiam W/DynamiteModule: Local module
>   descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not
>   found. 11-21 14:45:44.706 15899-15971/com.example.android.hereiam
>   W/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module via V2:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.android.hereiam-1/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.android.hereiam-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.android.hereiam-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.android.hereiam-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.android.hereiam-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.android.hereiam-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.android.hereiam-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.android.hereiam-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.android.hereiam-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.android.hereiam-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.android.hereiam-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.android.hereiam-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.hereiam-1/lib/arm64,
>   /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]] 11-21 14:45:44.737
>   15899-15971/com.example.android.hereiam I/DynamiteModule: Considering
>   local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote
>   module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4 11-21 14:45:44.737
>   15899-15971/com.example.android.hereiam I/DynamiteModule: Selected
>   remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version
>
> > = 4 11-21 14:45:44.763 15899-15971/com.example.android.hereiam W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
> >     /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000038/n/arm64-v8a

Answer (score 3):

You should implement LocationListener and don't try to cast your activity to LocationListener.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {
```

Implement the LocationListener methods

And replace this

```
 (LocationListener) this
```

To this

```
 this
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement  LocationListener in you MapsActivity class. then you can do as flows :
replace this line

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);
```

with this :

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

and this line :

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (LocationListener) this);
```

with this :

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
```

Comment: i have added as instructed but still getting errors. please what do i do here